# SSE instruction addressing methods and operand types in virtual real mode / real mode / 16-bit protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, disassembly, capstone

I'm trying to figure out some of the SSE instruction set's  operand types in virtual real mode / real mode / 16-bit protected mode.

For example let's take the following [instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/phaddw:phaddd):

```
66 0F 38 01 /r PHADDW xmm1, xmm2/m128
```

The destination operand is an XMM register and the source operand is an XMM register or a 128-bit memory.

Now I couldn't find anything regarding the modes I've been mentioning in the Intel reference and the SSE instruction's operand types changing in these modes, but according to [capstone](https://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?opcodes=%5Cx66%5Cx0f%5Cx38%5Cx01%5Cx58%5Cxd6&arch=x86-16&endianness=little&baddr=0x00000000&dis_with_addr=True&dis_with_raw=True&dis_with_ins=True#disassembly) this instruction's source operand suddenly became a 64-bit memory operand, not to mention that it seems capstone just dismissed the mandatory `0x66` operand size prefix for this instruction and used the addressing `P` and `Q` instead of `V` and `W` (as mentioned in the Intel ref) for the destination and source operands accordingly, and thus disassembling it as:

```
66 0F 38 01 58 D6    phaddw mm3, qword ptr [bx + si - 0x2a]
```

with an MMX register instead of an XMM register as I would have thought.

To my understanding the correct disassembly should be:

```
phaddw xmm3, xmmword ptr [bx + si - 0x2a]
```

using 128-bit memory as the source operand, and using an XMM register as the destination operand.

So either capstone is wrong or I'm missing something regarding SSE instructions and 16-bit mode somewhere in the Intel ref.

Clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: You convinced me :) Also both `objdump` and `ndisasm` produce the expected result.

Comment: "Legacy SSE" works in real mode (AVX/anything with a VEX prefix doesn't), so capstone has to be wrong

Comment: @harold I see thanks for clarifying, I could find more legacy sse instructions that capstone doing funny business with which I couldn't explain, so I would now feel more comfortable assuming capstone is in the wrong here.

Comment: IIRC, I think even AVX works in 16-bit *protected* mode.  It's only real mode where VEX instructions fault as the [invalid encoding of LES / LDS they overlap with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898858/how-does-an-instruction-decoder-tell), because apparently some VM86 software (like NTVDM) also used that intentionally to trap to protected mode or to check for a VM.  [See Michael Petch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/63139570)  @Harold is correct that legacy SSE encodings work in real mode while VEX encodings don't (including BMI1 `andn` and similar).

Comment: @Jester I reported similar [NDISASM bug #1](https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=2463.msg11129#msg11129) concerning incorrect disassembly of ModR/M in 16bit mode.